# How to debug a crash application

Tags: android, debugging, xamarin

I'm working on an application with Xamarin (in Visual studio 2015) for android.

When I run my application in debug mode, sometime the application stop with message "MyApplication has stopped".

I've added this code in MainActivity :

```
// Catch Exception
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
AndroidEnvironment.UnhandledExceptionRaiser += AndroidEnvironment_UnhandledExceptionRaiser;
```

I added breakpoints add log in both functions, but I see no traces in log and the breakpoints are not reached.

How can I debug this kind of problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to debug your application through a persistent logger i.e. `adb logcat`. Sadly registering an unhandled exception handler does not guarantee it will be a "catch-all" as it might never reach that point. So you will need a combination of both `adb logcat` and `Console.WriteLine` for these types of issues. Please take the following note into account when you want to see what's going on within this handler, but also make use of `adb logcat` to see the reason of the crash in the first place.

```
/// <summary>
/// When app-wide unhandled exceptions are hit, this will handle them. Be aware however, that typically
/// android will be destroying the process, so there's not a lot you can do on the android side of things,
/// but your xamarin code should still be able to work. so if you have a custom err logging manager or 
/// something, you can call that here. You _won't_ be able to call Android.Util.Log, because Dalvik
/// will destroy the java side of the process.
/// </summary>

protected void HandleUnhandledException (object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
{
    Exception e = (Exception) args.ExceptionObject;

    // log won't be available, because dalvik is destroying the process
    //Log.Debug (logTag, "MyHandler caught : " + e.Message);
    // instead, your err handling code shoudl be run:
    Console.WriteLine ("========= MyHandler caught : " + e.Message);
}
```

https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/fb9d4ed266bdf68bb1f9fa9933130b285712ec82/AdvancedAppLifecycleDemos/HandlingCrashes/App.cs

Answer (score 1):

Try it: Disabled "Use Shared Runtime"  in Android build options. If it not helped try - disable "Use fast deplayment".